# Why are some of the image links broken on the server but work fine offline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I have been working on this website recently and once everything was working offline, I put it up online. However, now some of the images won't show. And the weirdest thing is that the images that DO show are in the same directory.
I've been scratching my head on this for a while. Some help would be really appreciated.

Here is the website link: http://mcmaster.ca/chaplain/index-2.html

PS. I already tried renaming the images, removing spaces, etc.

Comment: It looks pretty clear cut that the missing images just haven't been uploaded to the server; [here's one of them, just giving a 404 error](http://mcmaster.ca/chaplain/img/Daughters-of-Abraham-Spring-2015.jpg)

Comment: They ARE on the server. Thus the confusion :/

Comment: They might be somewhere on the server, but clearly they're not at that URL -- click on that link and see for yourself.

Comment: The problem is definitely on the server's end, I know that. The entire website works just fine when I tested with WAMP server. What I'm asking is, what is that problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: We can't really tell since we can't see the file tree of the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but I can get you the information that could help fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your photos formats. `.jpg` and `.JPG` or `.jpeg` / `.JPEG` has a huge differents. Your `src` code not working, because your image format is `.JPG`, not `.jpg`

NOT WORKING: 
http://mcmaster.ca/chaplain/img/Daughters-of-Abraham-Spring-2015.jpg

WORKING: http://mcmaster.ca/chaplain/img/Daughters-of-Abraham-Spring-2015.JPG

Comment: OMG! You're a genius. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

"The requested URL /chaplain/img/Daughters-of-Abraham-Spring-2015.jpg was not found on this server."

It's not uploaded. :)